# R: Wrap text within grid.table when string exceeds set length

Tags: r, gridextra

I am using grid.table within the gridExtra package to display a list of survey comments in table format.  When the comments(string variable) exceeds a given length I want it to automatically insert a line break "\n".

```
library(gridExtra)
df<-data.frame(comments = c("Here is a short string", 
"Here is a long string that needs to be broken in half so that it doesn't run off the page",
"Here is another short string"))

grid.newpage()
print(grid.table(df$comments))
```

I am open to using a different table package if this feature is available elsewhere.

Comment: try `RGraphics::splitString`

Comment: When I run using splitString it only prints the first comment.       print(grid.table(splitString(df$comments)))

Comment: actually, this cannot work because splitString tries to fit in a given viewport, while grid.table adjusts the viewport to fit the content (vicious circle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use strwrap,

```
 d = sapply(lapply(df$comments, strwrap, width=50), paste, collapse="\n")
 grid.table(d)
```

Comment: Works...thank you very much.  I came across strwrap earlier but was having trouble getting it to work.  I did not use the sapply and lapply commands.  I really need to spend some time getting my head wrapped around how those functions work.

Comment: `s/lapply(list, fun)` is equivalent to `for(ii in 1:length(list)) fun(list[[ii]])` and collects the results in a vector/list.